# How to Match the list of values which are being passed from Input controls with column in the table in Vertica DB SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

```
Select * from Network 
where systemid in $P{objectid}
```

When I tried this it is not working because the output of the parameter Objectid is in the form of [10.129.148.163 10.130.149.111]. Hence it is throwing SQL statement error.

Then I tried using of Replace function. Ex:

```
 (REPLACE( replace(replace('[10.129.148.163,10.130.149.111]', '[', '('''),']',''')') , ',', ''','''))
```

This replace function is giving output as ('10.129.148.163','10.130.149.111')

But when Im using the same in where clause it is not working:

```
Select * from Network 
where systemid in (REPLACE( replace(replace('[10.129.148.163,10.130.149.111]', '[', '('''),']',''')') , ',', ''','''))
```

The output is giving blank.

Then I tried using JOIN,

```
Select * from Network N
inner join (select distinct (REPLACE( replace(replace('[10.129.148.163,10.130.149.111]', '[', '('''),']',''')') , ',', ''',''')) as neid )t on 1=1 
where (t.neid ilike '%'||N.systemid||'%' and not (t.neid  not ilike '%'||N.systemid||'%' ))
```

Then it is giving output as below

```
10.129.148.163
10.129.148.1
10.130.149.111
10.130.149.1
```

But the expected output is

```
10.129.148.163
10.130.149.111
```

I have tried my best but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a string of format `'[10.129.148.163 10.130.149.111]'` as a list of literals in an `IN()` predicate.

But, in Vertica, you can convert such a string to an array, and then `EXPLODE()` that array into an in-line table with which you can join.

As your Vertica version seems to be pre- 9.3, I add a script that uses `SPLIT_PART()` on your argument , after cleaning it of the square brackets using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` on a single-row table containing your search argument as its only column CROSS JOIN-ed with a series of consecutive integers. See the end of the post.

I'm using VSQL, Vertica's command-line SQL client. That one has a different format to use parameters / variables, the colon, followed by the variable name. So you will have to modify the script to contain `$P{objectid}` instead of my `:objectid`

```
\set objectid '''[10.129.148.163 10.130.149.111]'''
-- create some test data. Zurich and Berne satisfy the where condition.
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
networks(systemid,dom,city)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT '10.129.148.163','foo.co.ch','Berne'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.111','bar.co.ch','Zurich'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.112','chk.co.ch','Basle'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.113','tst.co.ch','Lugano'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.113','kil.co.ch','Geneva'
)
;

WITH
search(pos,objid) AS (
  SELECT
    EXPLODE(
     STRING_TO_ARRAY(
       :objectid  -- put parameter here
       USING PARAMETERS collection_delimiter=' '
      )
    ) OVER(PARTITION BEST)
)
-- ctl select * from search;
-- ctl  pos |     objid      
-- ctl -----+----------------
-- ctl    0 | 10.129.148.163
-- ctl    1 | 10.130.149.111
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  networks.* 
FROM networks
JOIN search
 ON systemid=objid;
-- out CREATE TABLE
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 56.730 ms. All rows formatted: 56.886 ms
-- out     systemid    |    dom    |  city  
-- out ----------------+-----------+--------
-- out  10.129.148.163 | foo.co.ch | Berne
-- out  10.130.149.111 | bar.co.ch | Zurich
```

Pre-Vertica-9.3 version:

```
\set objectid '''[10.129.148.163 10.130.149.111]'''
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
networks(systemid,dom,city)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT '10.129.148.163','foo.co.ch','Berne'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.111','bar.co.ch','Zurich'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.112','chk.co.ch','Basle'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.113','tst.co.ch','Lugano'
UNION ALL SELECT '10.130.149.113','kil.co.ch','Geneva'
)
;

WITH
objectid(objectid) AS (
  SELECT :objectid
)
,
i(i) AS ( -- need as many consecutive integers as we have IP addresses - 
            SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3
)
,
search(i,objid) AS (
  SELECT
    i
  , SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_REPLACE(:objectid,'[][]',''),' ',i) AS objid
  FROM objectid CROSS JOIN i
  WHERE objid <> ''
)
-- ctl SELECT * FROM search;
-- ctl  i |     objid      
-- ctl ---+----------------
-- ctl  1 | 10.129.148.163
-- ctl  2 | 10.130.149.111
SELECT
  networks.*
FROM networks
JOIN search
 ON systemid=objid;
-- out     systemid    |    dom    |  city  
-- out ----------------+-----------+--------
-- out  10.129.148.163 | foo.co.ch | Berne
-- out  10.130.149.111 | bar.co.ch | Zurich
```

Comment: Hi,  
 WITH
search(pos,objid) AS (
  SELECT
    EXPLODE(
     STRING_TO_ARRAY(
       :objectid  -- put parameter here
       USING PARAMETERS collection_delimiter=' '
      )
    ) OVER(PARTITION BEST)
)
 select * from search 

I tried to run this and given value as '[10.129.151.193]' when it prompted, but its throwing as error as "SQL Error [3457] [42883]: [Vertica][VJDBC](3457) ERROR: Function STRING_TO_ARRAY(unknown) does not exist, or permission is denied for STRING_TO_ARRAY(unknown)"

Comment: What's your Vertica version? `STRING_TO_ARRAY()` has been under support since version 9.3 - and we are at Version 12 currently. I'll add a "prehistoric" way of achieving what you need.

Comment: STRING_TO_ARRAY() is working but Explode is not working showing error as EXPLODE(varcha[]) does not exist or permissions denied

Comment: The expected out but and the current out but both are different, the expected out is what you have mentioned after select * from search but the current output is below 10.129.151.193,10.129.155.4 . I had run the same query

Comment: with  objectid(objectid) AS (
  SELECT :objectid
)
,
i(i) AS ( -- need as many consecutive integers as we have IP addresses - 
            SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3
)
,
search(i,objid) AS (
  SELECT
   
  i,
  
  SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_REPLACE(:objectid,'[][]',''),' ',i) AS objid
  FROM objectid CROSS JOIN i
  WHERE objid <> ''
)

select * from search

Comment: Im getting the expected output but in i(i) AS ( -- need as many consecutive integers as we have IP addresses - 
            SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3
 
) of the query we can pass only 3 values as input but when we pass more than 3 values then it is not working

Comment: That is why I added the comment that you even added in your comment above: Add `UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL (_as many as you need_)` to make it work.

Comment: You have very probably not run the same query. With the VSQL meta command `\set objectid '''[10.129.148.163 10.130.149.111]'''`` , `REGEXP_REPLACE()` removes the square brackets. And `SPLIT_PART()` of that "cleaned string", with the single space as the split delimiter (`' '`) , when `i` is 1, will return `10.129.148.163`; , when `i` is 2, it will return `10.130.149.111`. You must have a different pair of IP addresses in `:objectid` .